# SQL simply select * from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I simply want to get all Data from two tables.

So I thought I simply use this query:

```
SELECT * From mainpost,mainside
```

But the result is this:
[image]

So I thought I use joints but theres no ID's or something to compare.

Any Ideas?

Comment: you use `CROSS JOINTS`! :D

Comment: And which 'JOINTS' would be the right?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: If there are no common attribute, why join?

Comment: How should I format a sql result please? In phpmyadmin

Comment: When editing, mark the text and click `{}` to get formatting.

Comment: Thanks but I think the people can live with that when I use once a picture instead of making it as complicated as possible

Comment: There's a good tutorial in German for you: http://www.peterkropff.de/tutorials/php_mysql_3/left_right_join.htm

Comment: Theres is nothing to compare, so I can't use this querys...

Comment: You should specify the column name that you need in Select

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that wish it helps you:

```
    SELECT * FROM mainpost
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM mainside
```

Comment: Assuming this is what OP wanted, a decent answer. However, the columns don't line up, so you'll either have to exclude `imagefolder` or add a blank aliased column for it. In general using `SELECT * FROM ...` can be dangerous, particularly in `UNION`s when one table may change and therefore cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a UNION query rather than a JOIN since you seem to be implying that there is no field to compare between the two.

UNION requires that you have the same number of columns in the records that you combine which is very nearly the case in the example you give, unless it is just out of view in your screenshot - another reason for not posting images. So, you'd need to decide whether to keep the Imagefolder column or drop it entirely from the combined result - it's empty in the example so it may be safe to drop.

The query would then look like this

```
SELECT `ID`, `title`, `text`, `timestamp`
FROM `mainpost`
UNION ALL
SELECT `ID`, `title`, `text`, `timestamp`
FROM `mainside`
```

or

```
SELECT `ID`, `title`, `text`, `timestamp`, `Imagefolder`
FROM `mainpost`
UNION ALL
SELECT `ID`, `title`, `text`, `timestamp`, '' AS `Imagefolder`
FROM `mainside`
```